What to do to avoid rounding off decimal in SqlBulkCopy from C# to SQL Server?
I am importing .csv file data into a SQL Server table using SqlBulkCopy. My .csv file can be of any format as I can't determine the columns in it and the datatypes of it as same column can have decimal and text values, so I need to pass the value as such in the .csv file. But for some reason, some .csv files decimal points getting rounding off.
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(apsrcfile);
string Headline = File.ReadLines(Csvfilepath).ElementAt(0);|
string[] Headerline = Headline.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < Headerline.Length; i++)
 {
    csvData.Columns.Add();
 }
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvfilepath);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
string[] col = line.Split(',');
}
csvData.Rows.Add(col);
streamreader.Dispose();

SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Live"].ConnectionString);
objConn.Open();

SqlBulkCopy objbulkinsert = new SqlBulkCopy(objConn);
objbulkinsert.DestinationTableName = "Mappingtable";

foreach (DataColumn column in csvData.Columns)
{
    objbulkinsert.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName.ToString(), column.ColumnName.ToString());
}

objbulkinsert.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
objbulkinsert.WriteToServer(csvData);
objConn.Close();
                    

It works for other files. I don't know whether the .csv file is of problem, but opening it in notepad it shows the decimal point. I will attach the image of .csv file and SQL output I got.


Expected output: as such as .CSV file data in the SQL Server table.

What is csvData and have you checked that data is correct in there?

Pls show Mappingtable column data types.

Please don't use images, use formatted text.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Looks like Column2 is an integer data type. Change it to decimal

@Squirrel Can it be of integer type but shows as decimal in csv and also datatable?
And I had checked while debugging, the datatable datatype of Column2 is shown as string.

@Squirrel Can you provide me a code to change the datatype. As I can't change the file as it is from vendor.

@ValNik Mappingtable has all columns as varchar(100)

@Ralf  CsvData is a datatable

Relook at your csv. Not in Excel that already interprets data to show it in tabular style. Just look at it in notepad or any other simple editor. Paste a few lines here instead of the picture as pure text. Then debug your code and look directly into your datatable what data is inside there and if the problematic column has already trimmed the data.   WHen you say csv also show how you got from the csv to a datatable. Thats not just simply a given.

CsvData is a datatable - how CSV converted to DataTable? You may have already converted double->int at this stage.

@ValNik I have edited and shared the code of datatable.

@Ralf In notepad it shows as decimal only.

Table Design Matters
The table design of the target table and the view of the CSV is unknown. It makes difficult to answer. Column2 in destination table can be DECIMAL or MONEY and it must have 2 decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point. If the data type is DECIMAL without any decimal digits that
upload data without decimal digits.  This may have happened to you.
I assumed the text file(MappingTable.CSV) is something like it
/94HD012,194.37,10
/94HD013,483.37,
/94HD014,100,1
11-0001,112.57,100

The structure of the destination will be
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MappingTable](
    [Column1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Column2] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [Column3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Column4] [varchar](50) NULL
)

Finally, it properly works with the following code.
        private void btnSQLBulkCopyCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            string ConnStr = "Data Source= MyDB; Database=Learning; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            objConn.Open();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"E:\\Learning\\CSharp\\SampleData\MappingTable.csv"))
            {
                string[] headers = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                int columnCount = headers.Count();
                DataColumn[] columns; //
                columns = Enumerable.Range(1, columnCount).Select(x => new DataColumn($"Column{x}")).ToArray();
                dataTable.Columns.AddRange(columns);

                DataRow dataRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    dataRow1[i] = headers[i];
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow1);

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] rows = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dataRow[i] = rows[i];
                    }
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }
                SqlBulkCopy objbulkinsert = new SqlBulkCopy(objConn);
                objbulkinsert.DestinationTableName = "Mappingtable";

                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    objbulkinsert.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName.ToString(), column.ColumnName.ToString());
                }

                objbulkinsert.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                objbulkinsert.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                objConn.Close();
            }
        }


This was implemented on .Net Framework 4.7.2

But it works for me for other csv files,,Like if the csv file has decimal in 3rd column and Mappingtable is as varchar(100), it inserts with decimal data..So why not accepting in column2

@Gowsi
Normally it works. Just now I test it. But, as you noticing the problem, please provide me the SQL Server Table Structure and CSV file. Then I can give you the real feedback.
Thanks
